# how can i upload file to server using FormData?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I try to file upload to spring server using `FormData` object. And I hide input for `type="file"`. However, when I submit form, it is not working. I don't know where is incorrect.

This is part of `html`. when some button is clicked, `saveFiles()` is called.

```html
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 

<form name="fileForm" id="fileForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input style="display:none" type="file" id="fileSelector" name="fileSelector" multiple="" />
  <input type="hidden" id="docId" value="${doc.id}" />
  <div id="files"></div>
</form>

(function (global, $) {
  ...
  initFilehandler();
  ...
}

function initFilehandler() {
  document.querySelector('#fileSelector').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
  selDiv = document.querySelector("#files");
}

function saveFiles() {
  $("form#fileForm").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
   
  var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
   
  console.log(formdata);
    $.ajax({
      url: "/rd/file/save",
      type: "POST",
      data: formData,
      async: false,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function () {
        alert("success");
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just use formdata for uploading files. There's a lot of options for this one. But Im giving you a less complicated one.

Try using this plugin:

[jQuery Form](https://github.com/malsup/form)

I've been using that for years especially multiple file uploads. Good thing.. these plugin has callback for upload progress.. you can make a progress bar or something out of it..